# get height of LI using jQuery so news ticker scrolls up the exact amount needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, news-ticker

I am using a script from 
http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/jquery-how-to-create-a-news-ticker-with-just-a-few-javascript-lines/

which is a great newsticker, designed to scroll up just one article at a time, then append it again at the end in a continuous loop. But the limitation of this script is that the news items in each

have to be the same height as eachother, which isn't always possible.

I have been trying to modify the script so that it will automatically get the outerheight of '#ticker li:first'. and scroll it so that marginTop equals the negative of that outerheight. rather than the default '-120px'. But i've realised it's written as CSS style, i don't know how to rewrite it. Help!

here's the original script:

```
$(function()
{
    var ticker = function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-120px'}, 800, function()
            {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style'); 
            });
            ticker();
        }, 4000);
    };
    ticker();
});
```

Comment: Try:
`var oHeight = $('#ticker li:first').outerHeight();`
`$('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: -oHeight},...`

Comment: If I understood your question, that's all you need. The default unit is pixels so you don't have to worry about appending px

Comment: thankyou for such a quick response, what you've done looks a lot like what I was trying, but without the var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Just put the height into a variable, multiply by -1 (to make the negative number you need), and then drop it into the `marginTop` property:

```
$(function() {
    var ticker = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // get the height of the li element, multiply by -1 to be negative
            var h = parseInt($("#ticker li:first").outerHeight()) * -1; 
            $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: h + 'px'}, 800, function() {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style'); 
            });
            ticker();
        }, 4000);
    };
    ticker();
});
```

Comment: oh wow! that's perfect! thankyou! it's great because it shows me how to set the var first which i wanted to do but wasn't sure where!

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the outerHeight (including border, padding, and optionally margin) of an html element using jQuery, do [`$(element).outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

To retrieve the innerHeight of an html element using jQuery, do [`$(element).innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

```
$(function()
{
    var ticker = function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var oHeight = $('#ticker li:first').outerHeight();
            $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: -oHeight}, 800, function()
            {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style'); 
            });
            ticker();
        }, 4000);
    };
    ticker();
});
```

The default unit is pixels so you don't have to worry about appending px to the value.